# Protobuf-net and generics

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have a problem with protobuf-net and the use of generics.

Given:

```
    [DataContract]
public class CacheData
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public List<CacheLoadItem<int>> Foo;

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public List<CacheLoadItem<int>> Bar;

    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public List<CacheLoadItem<int>> XXX;

    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public List<CacheLoadItem<string>> YYY;

    [DataMember(Order = 5)]
    public List<CacheLoadItem<int>> Other;

    [DataMember(Order = 6)]
    public List<CacheLoadItem<int>> Other2;

    [DataMember(Order = 7)]
    public List<CacheLoadItem<int>> Other3;

    [DataMember(Order = 8)]
    public List<CacheLoadItem<string>> EvenMore;

    [DataMember(Order = 9)]
    public List<CacheLoadItem<string>> AlmostThere;
}

[DataContract]
public class CacheLoadItem<V>
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public int ID;

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string Name;

    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public V Value;
}
```

The CacheLoadItem with a generic int lists get serialised just fine, but the CacheLoadItem with a generic string lists don't.

I think it has to do with what generic list gets serialized first.

The CacheLoadItem with a generic string lists contains the correct number of items, but with default/null values.

Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Which version of protobuf-net? and platform? (regular .net? mono? cf? Silverlight?). I'm not aware of a problem here, but will happily investigate.

Comment: Cannot reproduce locally: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/Examples/Issues/SO3083847.cs

Comment: .NET 3.5
protobuf-net.dll version 1.0.0.282

Im exposing protocol buffer serialized objects through ASP.MVC, and consuming them in a Windows Form Client.

Comment: Ill try the unit test against the dll I have, and with the non-scrambled property names.

Comment: for info, I ran the test against 2.0.x (not fully released), since that is what I have locally - but I'd be surprised (and very interested) if the test fails on 1.x

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it is definitely Entity Framework related.

the CacheData is pululated with LINQtoEF.

Like:

```
                        using (var myDatabase = new MyDatabase(entityBuilder.ToString()))
        {
            result.A = (from a in myDatabase.ATable select new CacheLoadItem<int> { ID = a.ID, Name = a.Name, Value = a.Number }).ToList();
            result.B = (from b in myDatabase.BTable select new CacheLoadItem<string> { ID = b.ID, Name = b.Name, Value = b.Code }).ToList();
            result.C = (from c in myDatabase.CTable select new CacheLoadItem<int> { ID = c.ID, Name = c.Name, Value = c.ID }).ToList();
            result.D = (from d in myDatabase.DTable select new CacheLoadItem<int> { ID = d.ID, Name = d.Name, Value = d.Number }).ToList();
            result.E = (from e in myDatabaseETable select new CacheLoadItem<int> { ID = e.ID, Name = e.Name, Value = e.Number }).ToList();
            result.F = (from f in myDatabase.FTable select new CacheLoadItem<string> { ID = f.ID, Name = f.Name, Value = f.Number }).ToList();
            result.G = (from g in myDatabaseGTable select new CacheLoadItem<string> { ID = g.ID, Name = g.Name, Value = g.Code }).ToList();
            result.H = (from h in myDatabaseHTable select new CacheLoadItem<int> { ID = h.ID, Name = h.Name, Value = h.Number }).ToList();
            result.I = (from i in myDatabaseITable select new CacheLoadItem<int> { ID = i.ID, Name = i.Name, Value = i.Number }).ToList();
        }
```

Does not work, but the following works.

```
            using (var myDatabase = new MyDatabase(entityBuilder.ToString()))
        {
            result.A = (from a in myDatabase.ATable select a).ToList().Select(b => new CacheLoadItem<int> { ID = a.ID, Name = a.Name, Value = a.Number }).ToList();
            result.B = (from b in myDatabase.BTable select b).ToList().Select(b=>new CacheLoadItem<string> { ID = b.ID, Name = b.Name, Value = b.Code }).ToList();
            result.C = (from c in myDatabase.CTable select c).ToList().Select(c=> new CacheLoadItem<int> { ID = c.ID, Name = c.Name, Value = c.ID }).ToList();
            result.D = (from d in myDatabase.DTable select d).ToList().Select(d=> new CacheLoadItem<int> { ID = d.ID, Name = d.Name, Value = d.Number }).ToList();
            result.E = (from e in myDatabaseETable select e).ToList().Select(e=> new CacheLoadItem<int> { ID = e.ID, Name = e.Name, Value = e.Number }).ToList();
            result.F = (from f in myDatabase.FTable select f).ToList().Select(f => new CacheLoadItem<string> { ID = f.ID, Name = f.Name, Value = f.Number }).ToList();
            result.G = (from g in myDatabaseGTable select g).ToList().Select(g=> new CacheLoadItem<string> { ID = g.ID, Name = g.Name, Value = g.Code }).ToList();
            result.H = (from h in myDatabaseHTable select h).ToList().Select(h=> new CacheLoadItem<int> { ID = h.ID, Name = h.Name, Value = h.Number }).ToList();
            result.I = (from i in myDatabaseITable select i).ToList().Select(i=> new CacheLoadItem<int> { ID = i.ID, Name = i.Name, Value = i.Number }).ToList();
        }
```

The difference is that I dont do the transformation in LinqToEF but in LINQtoObjects.

So I guess that EF is broken?

Comment: In the first sample with pure LinqToEF. The data is there before the serialization with ProtoBuf, but not after.

In the second with LintToObjects the data is there before and after serialization with ProtoBuf.

Comment: Well, I'll happily take a look, but an interesting thought : I've seen LINQ-to-SQL drop lazy data during serialization - it only knows about serialization due to the callback API. I can probably come up with a way (especially in "v2") to simply skip the callback API? But if you have found a workaround it might not be worth it?